# Texshop/Bibtex not compiling

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I'm using a lecture template and trying to compile my references, which are in the folder above, as a general database. I'm using Texshop and have tried Latex Bibtex latex latex and document is ignoring references.
Any tips?

```
\documentclass[english,course]{lecture} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx} %Loading the package 
\graphicspath{{figures/}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

blablablabla

\begin{thebibliography}{} 
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{../bibliography} 
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code fragment has some mutually exclusive and incompatible statements.  Also, the code fragment contains no `\cite` directives. Please provide some more realistic/usable information about what you're trying to do. Which error messages did you get when you ran BibTeX?

Comment: I am trying to include a reference list at the end of a lecture.

I get no error notifications and my document compiles with no apparent problems other than the lack of inclusion of the reference list at the end or recognition of citations (they appear as [?]).

Could you explain which statements are incompatible?.

My \cite directives are included in the document, but not in this example since they are not really relevant to my question.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `thebibliography` environment?

Comment: I initially had it without the bibliography environment as
>\bibliography{bibliography}
>\bibliographystyle{plain}
>\nocite{*}
 
and that didn't compile the references either :( 
Scrolling back a couple of geological eras I can see some warnings for citations undefined, and then some further warnings about font size. This is my first time using the [english,course]{lecture}  package so I think there might be an incompatibility there with introducing a bibliography at the end of the lecture?

Comment: The document class file `lecture.cls` does not appear to be distributed with TeXLive (or MacTeX). Is it available online?

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to find the link, one sec :)

Comment: THis is the template I am using. It does not contain a bibliography and I just added it in -what seemed a logical way to do so- https://github.com/vhbelvadi/LaTeX-lecture-notes-class

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions and observations, not necessarily in any particular order.

- The fact that the citation call-outs show up as `[?]` in the body of the compiled document strongly suggests that you either haven't run BibTeX at all, or that BibTeX couldn't find the bib file, and/or that the bib file contains bibliographic entries that are characterized by such severe syntax errors that they cause BibTeX to crash. Since you haven't shown us any entries in the bib file, it's not possible for me to narrow down the diagnosis.
- The code fragment you've posted informs BibTeX that the bib file is called `bibliography.bib` and that this file located in the *parent directory* of the directory that contains the main tex file. Is this the case?
- If your main tex file is called `main.tex` (very original, I know...), then BibTeX should write the log of its activities to a file called `main.blg`. Does this file exist? If so, what does it say?
- You should delete the directives `\begin{thebibliography}{}` and `\end{thebibliography}` *immediately*. They should only ever be employed by authors who wish to build the bibliography entirely by hand. That's not the plan here, is it?
- Run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX *twice more*. You mention that you use TeXshop; to run BibTeX from within TeXshop, select "BibTeX" from the drop-down menu that's to the immediate right of the "Typeset" button. The result should be a pdf file with numeric-style citation call-outs (assuming you're using the `plain` bib style) and a properly formatted bibliography.
- Let's assume the bib file is called `mybib.bib`, that it's located in the *same* directory as the main tex file, called `main.tex`, and that there are no syntax errors in the bib file. Let's also assume that the files `lecture.cls` and `commons.sty` have been downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/vhbelvadi/LaTeX-lecture-notes-class) and stored in the same directory as `main.tex`. A minimalist `main.tex` suitable for bibliography creation should have roughly the following "look"

  ```
  \documentclass[english,course]{lecture}
  %% create 'mybib.bib' "on the fly":
  \begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
  @book{hartmann2013principles, 
    title  = {Principles of Musical Acoustics}, 
    author = {Hartmann, William M.}, 
    year   = {2013}, 
    publisher={Springer} 
  }
  \end{filecontents} 

  \bibliographystyle{plain}
  \title{aaa}

  \begin{document}  
  \cite{hartmann2013principles}
  \bibliography{mybib}
  \end{document}
  ```

  The relevant output of running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more on this file should look like this:

[image]

If your output does *not* look this, there may well be something wrong with your TeX distribution.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is quite useful :) 
I have run bibtex and done the usual bibliography compilation ritual, but it just keeps ignoring the file. 
Syntax errors do look promising, will follow that one too.
:)

Comment: @AmayaLópez-c - Please elaborate on what "[BibTeX] just keeps ignoring the file" entails. In particular, *which file* are you talking about?

Comment: Just ran it again to follow your bulletpointed debugging. Here's the diagnosis so far:
-My bib file is a standalone file with the bib references as copied from google scholar:
eg:

@book{hartmann2013principles,
  title={Principles of musical acoustics},
  author={Hartmann, William M},
  year={2013},
  publisher={Springer}
}

-Yes, .bib file was in parent folder, but just moved it back in for ease (changed routing in \bibliography{} accordingly)
-No .blg document produced

Comment: By ignoring I mean that document does compile, for both latex and bibtex, without crashes, but process does not result in a list of references at the end.

Comment: If no file called `main.blg` exists, BibTeX has *not* been run properly. Please tell us *how* you run BibTeX.

Comment: I run BibTeX from main.tex selecting Program>BibteX and then Typeset

Comment: Incidentally, when did you last update your TeX distribution?

Comment: that will be 2.5 years ago after I submitted my PhD thesis... xD

Comment: MAYBE that is the problem...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129826/discussion-between-amaya-lopez-c-and-mico).

Comment: @AmayaLópez-c - I've updated my sample code to include the tidbits of information  you've provided in the meantime. (It would have been *very useful* if you had provided this information up front...) Do try to compile this sample code. If it doesn't compile correctly, there may be something wrong with your TeX distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue after reinstalling MacTex to no avail.
The problem seemed to be that selecting BibTex as programfrom the TexShop window fails to process the .bib file, and BibTex MUST be selected as the Typesetter from the main workspace bar. I thought these were equivalent processes, but apparently they aren't!.
Hopefully this helps someone else.

Comment: Using the sample file from Mico's answer, I had equivalent results from either: (1) on the source window choosing LaTeX then pressing Typeset button there, next choosing BiBTeX and pressing Typeset button there, finally choosing LaTeX again and pressing Typeset there; and (2) from main TeXShop menu bar selecting item Typeset > LaTeX,, again from main menu bar selecting Typeset > BiBTeX, and finally from main menu bar selectint either Typeset > Typeset or Typeset > Pdftex.